# Bad：Can't finish "storage_client = storage.Client()" in google cloud speech

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-speech

Thank you for helping me！
When I use google cloud speech in Jupyter notebook, the error happened when I ran the following codes:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] =  os.path.join(os.path.realpath('.'),'Lu/Lu-xxxxxxxxxx.json')

os.path.join(os.path.realpath('.'),'Lu/Lu-xxxxxxxxxx.json')

with open("Lu/Lu-xxxxxxxxxx.json") as f:
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS = f.read()

def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
    from google.cloud import speech
    ...
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    audio = ...
    config = ...
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    ...
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)
    ...

# Imports the Google Cloud Storage client library
from google.cloud import storage
# Instantiates a client()
storage_client = storage.Client()
```

When reading the last line, it said `DefaultCredentialsError:File /home/luffy/Lu/Lu-xxxxxxxxxx.json was not found.`

But I'm sure the .json is there. Is there some problems with my project authentication configuration?

When I look at these problems, I feel that I lack some bacic knowledge. I don't fully understand the relation between google cloud speech and python, etc. Where can learn them?

Thank you!

Comment: You’re sure of nothing until you copy-paste the file path from the error message into your shell, right after `stat ` :) I’d suggest naming the file with a short, sensible name.

Comment: Thank you! I tried and I can `stat` the file. What will happen if I have a long complicated name?

Comment: I have tried to run the code snippet that you have provided and I did not encounter this error. The error message suggests that the file is not to be found there. May I ask you to run this script outside of Jupyter, simply in a command line, or you could also use the Cloud shell? It would benefit to know if the error shown there would be the same.
Can you also post the full traceback so that it would be clearer what in the source code is causing this error?

Comment: Thank you Philipp! I've already solved the problems. It turns out to be some environment problem, which I didn;t solve in the process of setting up googld cloud! Thank you!

Comment: @LU Huang, may I ask you to post what you did as an answer, and later on, accept it? I have seen other questions with Jupyter Notebook and GCP, so, any future reference for the community would be nice

Comment: Of course, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that It may be a configureation problem. I didn't finish well all the 'setting up environment' process for google cloud. Fot this part [quickstart for ubuntu and Debian](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu), I changed the project to the project I'm working right now(I changed the my project on google cloud some time before, but didn't follow this website to change my project). The I set up 'virtualenv' environment for my local project folder. After these steps, I succeeded!